# How add app widget provider class

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, manifest, eclipse-adt

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

It explains how to declare it in Manifest:

> ```
> <receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider" >
> <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
> </intent-filter>
> <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
>            android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" /> </receiver>
> ```

And later it says how to add class:

> public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
>
> ```
> public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
>     final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
>
>     // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
>     for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
>         int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
>
>         // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
>         Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
>         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
>
>         // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
>         // to the button
>         RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
> R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
>         views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
>
>         // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
>         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
>     }
> } }
> ```

And it says I need to declare the class as a broadcast receiver.

So My question is: I have the receiver in my app, but how do I add the class and declare it as a ***broadcast*** receiver?
It would be helpful if someone posted an example code of receiver with class, so I know how to put it together.
I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm just new to this all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Right from the docs:](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider)

> The **AppWidgetProvider** class **extends BroadcastReceiver** as a convenience
>   class to handle the App Widget broadcasts. The AppWidgetProvider
>   **receives only** the event **broadcasts** that are **relevant to** the App
>   **Widget**, such as when the App Widget is updated, deleted, enabled, and
>   disabled.

In other words: Since your `ExampleAppWidgetProvider` is inheriting from `AppWidgetProvider` class it's also a `BroadcastReceiver` since the AppWidgetProvider extends `android.content.BroadcastReceiver`. So there's no need to declare your class explicity as a broadcast receiver. Furthermore that's what the docs say (once again):

> You must declare your AppWidgetProvider class implementation as a
>   broadcast receiver using the **receiver element** in the AndroidManifest

And as I see it, you already did that. ;)

Comment: But I don't have the class in my app (i.e. i don't have anything similar to this: public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) { final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

// Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);

}) Also, my app crashes when adding widget and in logcat, it says it's because class not found. What I have in my manifest is just the first quote in my question, not the second.

Comment: Ok, but this class is necessary if you wan't to add a `Widget` to your app. Right inside the `AppWidgetProvider` everything necessary for the Widget is handled, like inflating the view, showing text etc.

Comment: So code similar to the code in the second quote in my question is meant to go in app widget provider in res-xml?

Comment: It's meant to go in a `Java-Class` in your `/src` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your last comment was really helpful. I made the java-class, my app works fine now without crashing.